Tool(s) for echoing to a bash script only once if script is run more than once
Edit: It's unfortunate the downvotes. This isn't my problem. This is how Linux wants things done and the myriad of tools that have ad-hoc and inconsistent install scenarios. Me asking this question is me wanting to do the right thing without having to create, adopt, and maintain poorly written scripts that only work well if they run once and everything works perfectly the first time they're ran.

It often comes up that a script needs to echo something to a .bashrc or similar file. Since this also often comes up in the context of an install script, such a file write should only happen once because the install script may be run multiple times in the event of failures or edits.
As a concrete example, when installing asdf, one needs to write the following to the ~/.bashrc file:
# asdf
. "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"
. "$HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash"

If echo is simply used in the install script, and the script is run multiple times, then you'll get the above three lines duplicated that many times. That's what happens when you use a solution I've written in scripts before:
# Install asdf
sudo apt-get install curl git -y
git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git ~/.asdf --branch v0.13.1
echo $'\n# asdf' >> ~/.bashrc
echo '. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
echo '. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc


Now, I could handle this with a proper scripting language such as PowerShell or a scriptable programming language, but how do I handle this best in a pure bash script? Are there tools to help with this? I am assuming there is some magical concoction of utilities that could be strung together, and those are acceptable answers, but the more dedicated the tool is to this problem, the better.
I would probably expect a solution to do something like:
# <asdf-begin>
. "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"
. "$HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash"
# <asdf-end>

Bonus points if the parts of the script that do the actual in between parts change, then re-running the script will update between the begin and end lines instead of writing a whole new block.

Is this for when you as a user (you're installing some random tool) or you as a developer (you're the one providing the random tool)?

"It often comes up that a script needs to echo something to a .bashrc or similar file." - citation needed. $HOME/.bashrc is very rarely modified, and almost always with a text editor. PowerShell is a Windows thing, not Unix, and an attempt by Microsoft to finally make something resembling a "proper" scripting language.

Also, re: echo: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/367454

As a general rule, do NOT touch user's config files without their knowledge. If you need to modify bashrc, then have your install script print out a message explaining that to the user. I really hate it when programs go and touch my config files, assuming they know best. Note how asdf does exactly that: it tells you to modify your bashrc, it doesn't presume to do it for you.

@muru Yes, this is a tool for me to automate the setup of development environments.

@Vilinkameni The citation is every Unix tool that asks you to edit your .bashrc file. PowerShell is not just a Windows thing. It is cross-platform and works just fine on Linux, since almost a decade ago.

@terdon "As a general rule, do NOT touch user's config files without their knowledge." These are my files and other developers who would be aware of what the script does.

OK, fair enough then, but this really isn't clean even for your stuff which is most likely why you're getting downvotes. By the way, what would PowerShell do here that bash cannot? I can't think of any scripting language that has a ready tool for "add this to a file unless it is present". In all the ones I know, you would need to parse the file to see if it's present and then add it, you would need to implement the logic yourself. Does PowerShell have something specific for this?

I doubt PowerShell has a specific solution for this pre-packaged. It's just a nicer scripting language than Bash, and so the solution would be easier to write, understand, and maintain.

@bmitc No properly designed "Unix tool" modifies the user's shell initialization file on its own. It is just bad UX. Unix has had the shell since its conception, while Microsoft had only vastly inferior COMMAND.COM until 2006, when they made PowerShell. A version for Unix-like systems is collateral.

Before I show you how to solve your original question, first let me show you the proper way:
If you have root permissions, you can simply install the files into the directories intended for this purpose. This will install asdf for all users.
cp ~/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/asdf
cp ~/.asdf/asdf.sh /etc/profile.d/asdf.sh

If you do not have root permissions, install the completions script into ~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions/ as per Standard place for user defined bash_completion.d scripts? (This requires bash-completion to be installed). I am not aware of a standard user equivalent of /etc/profile.d/ but you can easily make your own: /etc/profile should contain these lines:
# Load profiles from /etc/profile.d
if test -d /etc/profile.d/; then
    for profile in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        test -r "$profile" && . "$profile"
    done
    unset profile
fi

Let's take inspiration from that and put the following lines into ~/.profile:
if test -d ~/profile.d/; then
    for profile in ~/profile.d/*.sh; do
        test -r "$profile" && . "$profile"
    done
    unset profile
fi

Then you can simply do cp ~/.asdf/asdf.sh ~/profile.d/asdf.sh. This will work even if asdf is already installed.
BTW, I recommend using your Linux distribution's package manager instead of manually installing software. Writing packages is not that hard. See repology for existing packages and here for an Arch Linux example.
Solving your original question
if grep -wq 'asdf.sh' ~/.bashrc; then
    : # asdf already installed, do nothing
else
    echo '. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
fi

For bonus points, you can use GNU sed to first remove the lines wrapped between <asdf-begin> and <asdf-end> and then write the updated block:
sed -i '/<asdf-begin>/,/<asdf-end>/d' ~/.bashrc
cat <<'EOF' >>~/.bashrc
# <asdf-begin>
. "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"
# <asdf-end>
EOF


Thanks for the great answer! I always like answers that provide both how you should do it and how you can do it given the original question. I will take a look at this more in depth later and accept the answer after that.

@bmitc FWIW, this is the general trend in which Linux software is heading (all the .d dirs like /etc/sudoers.d, /etc/cron.d, /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d, etc.).

I would honestly just grep for the lines in question. If they are in there, don't do anything and, if not, add the lines.
ex:
line1=$(grep "asdf.bash" ~/.bashrc)
if [ ! -z "$line1" ];
then
  echo "Lines are present, continue"
else
  echo '. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
  echo '. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash' >> ~/.bashrc
fi

This of course can be strung together to grep for more than one line or if you only need to grep for one to know that all 3 are in there then it's also enough.

if grep -qF asdf.bash ~/.bashrc; then ...; fi would be neater.
